# Apache HTTP LocationMatch Redirect using Negative RegEx

Tags: apache-2.4, redirect, regex

I'm trying to create a `Redirect` using Apache HTTP Server's [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and [core](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#locationmatch) on my system:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
# rpm -q httpd
httpd-2.4.6-31.el7_1.1.x86_64
#
```

requirement is to redirect all requests, except for request to `/server-status`

```
# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/_default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    <LocationMatch "^/!(server-status)(.*)?">
        Redirect / http://X/
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

I believe my issue is somewhere with regex, as I'm getting 404 no matter what URL I hit.

Comment: by the way you dont have DocumentRoot in your virtual host, did you added it somewhere else ? servername should be your comp name or domaine name is it normal you set _default_ ?

Comment: @Froggiz this is catch all `VirtualHost`, hence `ServerName` set to `_default_` and no `DocumentRoot` either. btw I'm about to try your answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 - You can do it using mod rewrite https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status
    RewriteRule (.*) http://X$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

2 - To use Mod_Alias you need `RedirectMatch` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!server-status)(.*) http://X/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - more info:

- once configuration has been changed, Apache needs to be restarted
- the server needs to be different else you will have a redirect loop

4 - Bonus

`(.*)` = catch all in regexp

`$1` = result var

`R` = redirect status code, here you have the list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

`L` = flag which mean Last, here you have the flag list codes:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

5 - Even more...
if you really want to use `LocationMatch` syntax is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  <LocationMatch "^/(?!server-status)(.*)">
    Redirect / http://X/
  </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I end up using `RedirectMatch`, everything works) Thanks!

Comment: i am happy it worked for you ^_^